# Why is FB.Event.subscribe no longer detecting when I've logged out of facebook?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

If I'm logged into facebook the testAPI() function fires as it's supposed to, but when I log out of facebook and refresh the page where my init code is, nothing happens. My console should log "not logged in", or "not authorized", but it doesn't. I've tried clearing the cache, but it doesn't work.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {

     //this works 

      testAPI();

    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {



      console.log("not authorized");

    } else {


      console.log("not logged in");
    }

  });

var testAPI = function() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`auth.authResponseChange` only fires when the status actually change, in your case it never change.

What you want is to use `FB.getLoginStatus`.